# Custom Editor. Value is not saved SerializedProperty.enumValueIndex

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

Good time of day.
I am not engaged in customization of the editor, but I decided to take a look at something and how, and at the same time organize my inspector.
Faced with the problem that getting private fields is not so easy. I read what should be done through reflection.
In the end, everything seemed to be fine until I ran into a problem:
For some reason, the value is not saved... Here is the code:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
 
[CustomEditor(typeof(Door))]
public class DoorEditor : Editor
{
    private Door _target;
    private SerializedObject _serializedObject;
 
    private SerializedProperty 
        _state,
        _startPoint;
 
    private void OnEnable() {
        _target = (Door)target;
        _serializedObject = new SerializedObject(_target);
 
        _startPoint = _serializedObject.FindProperty("_startPoint");
        _state = serializedObject.FindProperty("_state");
    }
 
    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical("box");
 
        _startPoint.objectReferenceValue = (Transform)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Start Point", _startPoint.objectReferenceValue, typeof(Transform), true);
 
        _state.enumValueIndex = (int)(DoorState)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup((DoorState)_state.enumValueIndex);
        //Actually the line above does not work. and to be more precise, even "_state.enumValueIndex = 1" does not change the value _state.enumValueIndex, why?...
 
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        EndOnInspectorGUI();
    }
 
    private void EndOnInspectorGUI() {
        if (_serializedObject != null)
            _serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
 
        if (GUI.changed) SetObjectDirty(_target.gameObject);
    }
 
    public static void SetObjectDirty(GameObject obj) {
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(obj);
        EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(obj.scene);
    }
}
```

The class for which Editor is written:

```
public class Door : MonoBehaviour, IInteract
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _startPoint; public Transform StartPoint => _startPoint;
    [SerializeField] private DoorState _state = DoorState.Open; public DoorState State => _state;
    [SerializeField] private DoorType _type = DoorType.Standart;
    [SerializeField, TextArea(1, 3)] private string _massage = "Error! Сообщение не назначено";
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource _audioSource;
    [SerializeField] private DoorOpeningSounds _doorOpeningSounds;
    public UnityEvent OnOpenDoor; 
    public UnityEvent OnEnterTheDoor;
 
 
    public void SetMassage(string newMassage) {
        _massage = newMassage;
    }
    public void SetState(DoorState newState) {
        _state = newState;
    }
 
    public void OpenTheDoor() {
        _audioSource.clip = _doorOpeningSounds.GetClip(_type);
        _audioSource.Play();
        OnOpenDoor.Invoke();
    }
 
    private void EnterTheDoor() {
        OpenTheDoor();
        OnEnterTheDoor.Invoke();
    }
 
    public void Interact() {
        if (_state == DoorState.Open) {
            EnterTheDoor();
        } else if (_state == DoorState.Loced) {
            SubtitlesManager.Instance.ShowSubtitles(new Subtitle("Закрыто", 2f), true);
        } else if (_state == DoorState.Broken) {
            SubtitlesManager.Instance.ShowSubtitles(new Subtitle("Ручка сломана", 2f), true);
        } else if (_state == DoorState.Bloked) {
            SubtitlesManager.Instance.ShowSubtitles(new Subtitle("Дверь что-то блокирует", 2f), true);
        } else if (_state == DoorState.NoActive) {
            SubtitlesManager.Instance.ShowSubtitles(new Subtitle("Не поддаётся", 2f), true);
        } else if (_state == DoorState.Massage) {
            SubtitlesManager.Instance.ShowSubtitles(new Subtitle(_massage, 2f), true);
        } else {
            Debug.LogError("Действие двери в состоянии " + _state + " не реализовано");
        }
    }
}
```

Enum is the most common:

```
public enum DoorState
{
    Open,
    Loced,
    Broken,
    Bloked,
    NoActive,
    Massage
}
```

It's not that I do not know how to set the value, I have already tried many ways. The fact is that the set value is reset at the next iteration of OnInspectorGUI.
If I install it and do checks and operations in one iteration, everything will work, but as soon as the next iteration starts, the value will immediately reset.
Somehow, after setting the value, I don't save it, but the general saving occurs at the end of each iteration in EndOnInspectorGUI();
Here is a video of how it is not possible to set the value: https://youtu.be/PZm9jiLxTM4

I tried various display options in the inspector. but the problem turned out to be that _state.enumValueIndex does not save the value if it is assigned

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles upon this in the future. The problem is within the editor workflow logic.
See, Unity Editor works with `SerializedObject` version of your script and thus, changes to properties (`_startPoint` and `_state`) are not applied automatically.

The usual workflow would be to do something like this

```cs
public override void OnInspectorGUI() 
{
    EditorGUILayout.BeginChangeCheck();
 
    _startPoint.objectReferenceValue = (Transform)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Start Point", _startPoint.objectReferenceValue, typeof(Transform), true);
    _state.enumValueIndex = (int)(DoorState)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup((DoorState)_state.enumValueIndex);

    if(EditorGUILayout.EndChangeCheck()) 
    {
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

note, `EditorGUILayout.BeginChangeCheck()` and `EditorGUILayout.EndChangeCheck()`, they capture all the changes to the `serializedObject` and allow to safely call the "save my changes now, please" method (`serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties`)

If you want to add an Undo feature to your editor, you would usually capture the modified property value to a temporary variable and before applying the changes you would do `Undo.RecordObject(serializedObject.targetObject)` before calling `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()`